# Is it thread safe to get an element by index from List

Tags: c#

Is it thread safe to get an element by index from List?

```
var list = new List<int>();
...
var a = list[i]; //executed from multiple threads. Should this be protected?
```

Comment: It depends on the list implementation, basically. `ArrayList` isn't threadsafe, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is...

Comment: If you are only getting elements from list, then its OK. If you are also changing list (setting, adding, removing), then you should lock collection

Comment: It depends what else you're doing.  Concurrent _reads_ are fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is absolutely thread safe...
...as long as you can make sure that the list is not changed. Even adding items puts you into "not defined" territoty (although depending on implementation it may just work).

So, read only - yes. Read + manipulation: no.

Note: it is ok to change items IN the lsit as long as the list[5] for example is the same object. The list does not care. Not saying it will work - because depending what you would change here that would be your contract with the objects in the list. For ints you obviously should not update them.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what action you wish to do.

Read - totally safe.

Write/ Edit - not so safe

There are  few collections categorized as `Concurrent Collections` which are threadsafe Out of the Box.

But, it is faster (in run time) to synchronize an existing `List<T>` rather then using a Concurrent Collection.